# iPhone does not discover Services on a Bluetooth LE tag on reconnection

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth LE application for iOS. I am using the Core Bluetooth framework within iOS to handle all communications.

**Question & Description:**

When I use a single tag, despite numerous connections and disconnections, the single tag connects seamlessly and the phone discovers it services.

Also, when multiple Bluetooth LE tags connect for the first time, they connect seamlessly and the phone discovers their services.
 
When the tags get disconnected and then reconnect to the phone, the tags connect fine. But one of the two tags (either one) does not seem to advertise its services. i.e when the app is open and the tag reconnects, the ***DiscoverServices*** method does not call the ***didDiscoverServices*** delegate.

Why is this happening only when connection with multiple devices takes place.

I have set the ***peripheral.delegate*** correctly. I have tried everything, including doing repeated re-connect, repeated DiscoverServices calls to the tag. Nothing seems to work.

How can I re-connect to multiple tags to the phone and still discover all services.


**Please help**

Thanks,
Manju

Comment: You should post some code for this. corebluetooth is a bit buggy, and I have myself had trouble with this callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there was command I was issuing to the device in the"***didDiscovercharacteristicsForService***" delegate method which was causing the connection instability. 

If you are facing similar issues, I suggest you to let the delegate method complete without any intervention (**of any kind**)  and pass the CBPeripheral to another function designed by you to pass any values / issue a command to the devices.

Thanks anyway Wilhemsen.

So the steps are as follows..
1> Search for Tag, 
2> If in range, CONNECT to Tag
3> If Connected, call DISCOVER services method (do not interrupt)
4> IN DidDiscoverServices, call DISCOVER Characteristics Method
..
In DidDiscoverCharacteristics Method, wait until all Characteristics are discovered..
Then , at the end, call a function in your code that will do the necessary setup..
...
**Code Sample**

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{

    for (int i=0; i < peripheral.services.count; i++) {
        CBService *s = [peripheral.services objectAtIndex:i];
        printf("Fetching characteristics for service with UUID : %s\r\n",[self CBUUIDToString:s.UUID]);
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:s];
    }

}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{        
    if (!error)
    {
        CBService *s = [peripheral.services objectAtIndex:(peripheral.services.count - 1)];
        if([self compareCBUUID:service.UUID UUID2:s.UUID])
        {
           // This is when the **Tag** is completely connected to the Phone and is in a mode where it can accept Instructions from Device well.

            printf("Finished discovering characteristics");
           // Now Do the Setup of the Tag
            [self setupPeripheralForUse:peripheral];

        }
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Characteristic discorvery unsuccessfull !\r\n");
    }
}

-(void) setupPeripheralForUse:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{

    // DO all your setup in this function. Separate Perpiheral Setup from the process that synchronizes the tag and the phone. 

}
```

Comment: Weird how I came back here :P Still the same problem for me, could you ellaborate on what command you issued? Or how your callback now looks like? It would be really helpful, thank you. PS: Glad to see you solved it :)

Comment: Hey Wilhelmsen, ,<br>
The main solution to the code is that we dont setup our preferences on the tag while the services and the characteristics are being discovered.
Once all the services and its characteristics are discovered, then we can call a setupPeripheral call.. I will add my code as another answer..

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem but realized that I wasn't setting the `delegate` to `CBPeripheral` after `didConnectPeripheral` is called.

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Peripheral Connected: %@", peripheral.name);

    peripheral.delegate = self;

    if (peripheral.services) {
        [self peripheral:peripheral didDiscoverServices:nil];
    } else {
        [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CUSTOM_UUID]]];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I was facing a similar issue with CoreBluetooth to connect to Bluetooth LE devices, in my case connecting to iOS devices (peripherals) from my Mac (central).

If I get you correctly, the pattern is quite consistent, the first time I run my Mac app for debuging, it always detected and connected to any bluetooth LE devices (peripherals), most importantly, it also discover their services/characteristics fine. The problem starts on the second run (for example, change some code, hit cmd-R to relaunch the debug). The central still detects peripherals and connects to them, but, it fails to discover any services/characteristics. In other words, the delegate `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` and `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:` never get called.

The solution after a lot of trial and errors, is surprisingly simple. It seems that CoreBluetooth caches `services` and `characteristics` for peripherals that are still connected, although locally it looks like it had been disconnected to the app, the peripheral still maintains a bluetooth connection to the system. For these type of connections, there is no need to (re)discover the services and characteristics, just access them directly from the peripheral object, check for `nil` to know if you should discover them. Also, as mentioned, since the peripheral is in a state that is in between connections, it is best to call `cancelPeripheralConnection:` right before attempting to connect. The gist of it as following, assuming we already discovered the peripheral to connects to:

```
-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    [central cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral]; //IMPORTANT, to clear off any pending connections    
    [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    peripheral.delegate = self;

    if(peripheral.services)
        [self peripheral:peripheral didDiscoverServices:nil]; //already discovered services, DO NOT re-discover. Just pass along the peripheral.
    else
        [peripheral discoverServices:nil]; //yet to discover, normal path. Discover your services needed
}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    for(CBService* svc in peripheral.services)
    {
        if(svc.characteristics)
            [self peripheral:peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:svc error:nil]; //already discovered characteristic before, DO NOT do it again
        else
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil
                                     forService:svc]; //need to discover characteristics
    }
}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    for(CBCharacteristic* c in service.characteristics)
    {
        //Do some work with the characteristic...
    }
}
```

This works well for me for a CBCentralManager in Mac app. Never tested it in iOS, but I assume it should be quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue. it seems to occur about 1/3 the time in my case. I tried the solution provided by P.L. but I had no success on iOS. There are perhaps many moving pieces at work here which can contribute to this problem (bluetooth device firmware, CoreBluetooth, etc.) but I solved it by simply keeping track of the devices which are pending service/characteristic discovery in an NSMutableDictionary and using GCD to check if it had completed it's discovery in a reasonable amount of time and trying again if necessary. So something like this:

```
- (void)requestDiscoverServicesForPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
{
      peripheral.delegate = self;
      NSString *uuid =[self stringUUIDForUUID:peripheral.UUID];
      NSLog(@"discovering %d services ", self.interestingServices.count);
      [peripheral discoverServices:self.interestingServices];
      [self.pendingConnectionDevices setObject:peripheral forKey:uuid];
       __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
      dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 *NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([weakSelf.pendingConnectionDevices objectForKey:uuid]) {

               //request discover services again
               NSLog(@"services did not discover, requesting again!");
               [weakSelf.btManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
               [weakSelf.btManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
         }
    });
 }
```

Then, when `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:error` calls back I remove it from my pendingConnectionDevices dictionary. This seems to work pretty well. I've seen it try to discover services up to 3 times before succeeding. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's hardware issue. I just encountered a case that the hardware will enter a sleeping mode which is scannable, connectable, but not calling back at all for discoverServices.

Also there's a situation that happened to me when developing BLE all night and suddenly, the device become silence for discoverServices no matter what I did. Finally I found it will become normal if I reboot my iPhone5s.

And one day the bluetooth hardware engineer told me that the spec of BLE only says device must be connectable again within 30 seconds. So if I connect and disconnect over and over again, it may not working as expected... Which I still doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to apply all above answers but it wasn't working for me because I was missing `CBPeripheralDelegate` on class.

```
class BLEHandler : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    peripheral.delegate = self

    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

    print("Connected: \(peripheral.state == .connected ? "YES" : "NO")")
  }

  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    for service: CBService in peripheral.services! {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        print(service)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing everything you say in your answer, but I still see this issue from time to time. My guess is Core Bluetooth gets into a weird state, probably due to a specific sequence of connection, subscription and disconnection.

The only way I've found to fix the problem is to restart the iOS device. This issue might be fixed in iOS 7.1 though.

Comment: Hi Mark,
One thing to watch out is that the BTLE radio follows a certain pattern where it interacts with one device connection query at a time. Perhaps you could run the discovery and services recognition functions on a string of NsOperation using a NsOperationQueue on a separate thread ? This has helped us a lot

Answer (score 0):

My headache was caused by lack of **strong reference to peripheral**

So I've add the reference and the problem is gone

```
private var activePeripheral: CBPeripheral?

func connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        disconnect(peripheral)
        activePeripheral = peripheral
        self.central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
```