# DiscoverServices never triggered sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Most of time, this works normally in my application. Unfortunately, sometimes it never been triggered after discoverservice is called.

My code is:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral     *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Did connect to peripheral: %@", peripheral);
    [self.delegate statusMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did connect to peripheral: %@\n", peripheral]];

    peripheral.Delegate = self;
    NSArray *serviceArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:_uuid_tpms_sensor_service];
                [_peripheral discoverServices:serviceArray];
    [peripheral discoverServices:serviceArray ];
}
```

Some posts relative with this are

- [CoreBluetooth never calls didDiscoverServices on iPhone5S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435809/corebluetooth-never-calls-diddiscoverservices-on-iphone5s)
- [iOS CoreBluetooth not scanning for services in iPad Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919373/ios-corebluetooth-not-scanning-for-services-in-ipad-air)
- [iPhone does not discover Services on a Bluetooth LE tag on reconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004623/iphone-does-not-discover-services-on-a-bluetooth-le-tag-on-reconnection/23116220#23116220)

The final conclusion should be an issue in iOS. My question is that, given that it's iOS problem, how to work around this?

Comment: Could anyone share the experience on this issue? I'm still working on this problem after days debugging.

Comment: That's a issue I encountered. I could do nothing about it, except reboot the iDevice or the BLE device (don't remember which one). Because, even LightBlue, after my app get "stucked", couldn't scan service too. iOS issue.

Comment: @Larme, Ditto. Even turn BT on and then off in Setting-->Bluetooth, the the state machine of Bluetooth API can't be recovered. Manju Kiran states "One thing to watch out is that the BTLE radio follows a certain pattern where it interacts with one device connection query at a time. Perhaps you could run the discovery and services recognition functions on a string of NsOperation using a NsOperationQueue on a separate thread ? This has helped us a lot" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004623/iphone-does-not-discover-services-on-a-bluetooth-le-tag-on-reconnection/23116220#23116220.

Comment: Complement the previous digest. Now I'm trying to implementation similar logic in application to work around this issue, wish it useful.

Comment: @Larme thanks for your comment. So, in your opinion, we can't do nothing about this issue except accept it? Ideally, given that there are so many BLE application and accessory in the market, I deem that there should be some work around for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Larme and henrik as I got many ideas from your reply.

After three days verification, it seems I have find a work around for this problem (the problem is more likely a limitation of Bluetooth stack of iOS rather than an issue)

I'd like to summarize my findings and work around here:

**[root cause]**

- Bluetooth stack in iOS　is not robust enough, it's therefore the internal state machine become corrupted after some unexpected API calling.
- As the BTLE radio follows a certain pattern where it interacts with one device connection query at a time, BLE application should `follow the API sequence of connectperiperal-->discover-->read-->disconnect` (trigger by local, peer device or supervision timeout on link layer).
- Apple admitted that this was an issue in iOS.

**[resolution]**

- follow the API calling sequence described in the above

Hope the summary is useful for other person.

Answer (score 0):

Too many rogue app's not handling the BLE stack properly can cause it to crash. Then the phone needs to be restarted. iOS7 and 8 are much more robust than in the early life of iOS BLE.
Android are still less robust. Programmers forget to release resources or might try to write new data before the old has been transmitted.

This can happen a lot if you use X-code and you stop your app at a point before it releases resources etc. This can still crash iOS BLE stack.